# DAx Formula Counting tasks

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a question regarding Dax formula in PowerBI. All help is appreciate. I need to present some results on monday...

[Table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paQGt.png)

Task column can have different fields (Partner Acknowledgment, IPM HandOff, Pre Engagement Process...)
Task status can only have 2 values (closed or Received)

I have my formulas that work but now I need to add an extra filter and is getting error:
THe Filter part is giving me problems (WHen task= IPM HandOff is Task_status = Closed)

**Total Tasks** = All the tasks  (rows) that contains the word "Partner Acknowledgment" in the task column.....And I try to add a filter when "IPM HandOff" in the task column has task_status closed:

```
Tasks =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTA ( CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK] ),
    CONTAINSSTRING ( CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK], "Partner Acknowledgement" ),
    FILTER (
        CELERGO_12062021V1,
        CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK] = "IPM HandOff"
            && CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK_STATUS] = "Closed"
    )
)
```

**Total Tasks with GLD** = Same as the previous one but with a schedule Date in the column Schedule.....And I try to add a filter when "IPM HandOff" in the task column is Task_status = closed.

```
Partner Acknowledgment with GLD = CALCULATE ( COUNTA ( CELERGO_12062021V1[SCHEDULED] ), CONTAINSSTRING ( CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK], "Partner Acknowledgement" )) ,
        FILTER (
            CELERGO_12062021V1,
            CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK] = "IPM HandOff"
                && CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK_STATUS] = "Closed"
        )
    )
```

**Total Tasks with GLD** = Same as the previous ones but with a schedule Date in the column Schedule and Task Status Closed for the task "Partner Acknowledgmeent".....And I try to add a filter when "IPM HandOff" in the task column is Task_status = closed.

Partner Acknowledgment with GLD & Closed = CALCULATE ( COUNTA ( CELERGO_12062021V1[SCHEDULED] ), CONTAINSSTRING ( CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK], "Partner Acknowledgement" ) && CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK_STATUS] = "Closed" ) ,
FILTER (
CELERGO_12062021V1,
CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK] = "IPM HandOff"
&& CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK_STATUS] = "Closed"
)
)

ANy idea got to add this extra field in the formulas? "WHen task= IPM HandOff is Task_status = Closed) Thanks :)

last part... Is it possible to get the formulas + extra filter counting only the tasks owned by some people (names??) I want to know the formulas below that belong to Taskactualperformer = Roger, Abbie and Veronika"?

---

Same table. I need to combined the 2 formulas below...

To get all the clients with

Task = "pre engagement Team" and Tast_Status (Closed and Received)   - Formula 1

&&

Task = "IPM HandOff" and Task_Status is Received     - Formula 2

Tried different options but no exit.

Formula1 = VAR result =

```
CALCULATE (

    DISTINCTCOUNT( CELERGO_12062021V1[CID] ),

    FILTER (

        CELERGO_12062021V1,

        CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK]

            = "Pre Engagement Process"

            && CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK_STATUS] IN  { "Closed", “Received” }

    )

)
```

RETURN

```
IF ( ISBLANK ( result ), 0, result )
```

FOrmula 2 =

VAR result =

```
CALCULATE (

    COUNT ( CELERGO_12062021V1[CLIENT_NAME] ),

    FILTER (

        CELERGO_12062021V1,

        CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK] = "IPM HandOff"

            && CELERGO_12062021V1[TASK_STATUS] = "Received"

    )

)
```

RETURN

```
IF ( ISBLANK ( result ), 0, result )
```

last part... Is it possible to get the formulas + extra filter counting only the tasks owned by some people (names??) I want to know the formulas below that belong to Taskactualperformer = Roger, Abbie and Veronika"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend splitting those measures into simple ones.
As I understand, you want to count the number of rows that contain 'Partner Acknowledgment' in the task column and add the number of rows that have the value "closed" in the status column and the value 'IPM HandOff' in the task column. Then you can try this:

Count rows:

```
Total Tasks =
COUNTROWS ( 'TableA' )
```

Count rows where tasks contain 'Partner Acknowledgment':

```
Partner_Acknowledgment_Total =
CALCULATE (
    [Total Tasks],
    CONTAINSSTRING ( 'TableA'[task], "Partner Acknowledgment" )
)
```

Count rows where tasks are equal to 'IPM HandOff' and status = 'closed'

```
IPM_HandOff_closed_Total =
CALCULATE (
    [Total Tasks],
    'TableA'[task] = "IPM HandOff",
    'TableA'[status] = "closed"
)
```

Final measure:

```
Partner_Acknowledgment+IPM_HandOff_closed =
[Partner_Acknowledgment_Total] + [IPM_HandOff_closed_Total]
```

Measures are for the table:

[image]